# Use a sprite C++ MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to display an image from a sprite using MFC. A search on google led me to this [link](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/2471/how-to-create-a-sprite-using-mfc/) which led me to this code :

```
//This code is in the OnPaint function

//img is a CImage, declared as a class member
img.Load(_T("icon-sprite.png"));
HDC imgDc = img.GetDC();

int height = 24;
int width = 24;

//Sprite Icon is a CStatic
CDC* spriteDc = spriteIcon.GetDC();
HDC spriteHdc = spriteDc->GetSafeHdc();

CClientDC pDC(this);
HDC hdcWindow = pDC->GetSafeHdc();

//img.StretchBlt(imgDc, 0, 0, 600, 203, SRCCOPY);
//img.BitBlt(imgDc, width, height, 600, 203, 0, 0, SRCAND);
//img.BitBlt(imgDc, width, height, 640, 480, 0, 0, SRCPAINT);

StretchBlt(imgDc, 0, 0, 600, 203,
    imgDc, 0, 0, 200, 203, SRCCOPY);

BitBlt(imgDc, width, height, 600, 203,
    imgDc, 0, 0, SRCAND);

BitBlt(imgDc, width, height, 640, 480,
    imgDc, 0, 0, SRCPAINT);

spriteIcon.SetBitmap((HBITMAP)img);
```

With this code `spriteIcon` only display a rectangle of the size of the sprite image.
What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Not directly related, but any drawing should be done in an `OnPaint` handler and not in `OnItitDialog`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I moved the code to OnPaint, It did not change the behavior, but at least the code is cleaner

Comment: It's hard to understand what's going on without seeing the whole picture. But be aware that the drawing code must be in `OnPaint`, because otherwise the sprint won't be drawn at all when the windows is redrawn (e.g. after beeing oncovered by another window).

Answer (score 1):

Most probably `CImage` is local and going out of scope, thus the image (and `HBITMAP`) is invalid. You have two options:

- Declare `CImage` such that it would exist even after this function returns.
- Use `CImage::Detach` which returns a `HBITMAP` and relinquishes its ownership with handle (i.e. won't delete on destructor).

Please ensure that given image exists and is loaded properly.

Also, you don't need to `new CClientDC`, you can have it on stack.

Comment: I edited my question, CImage is not local, it is a member, I can't use CImage::Detach because I used `GetDC` before and Detach require `m_hDC` to be NULL. I can't either use detach first because GetDC requires `m_hBitmap` (the member of CImage) not to be NULL, which it is if I call Detach first.

Comment: I meant: `spriteIcon.SetBitmap(img.Detach());`

Comment: And what's the type of `spriteIcon` ?

Comment: `CStatic`. yeah that's what I thought : `spriteIcon.SetBitmap(img.Detach());` does not work because I called `img.GetDC();` earlier in the code, `GetDC()` initialize the `m_hDc` of my CImage, and `Detach();` requires `m_hDc` to be NULL

Comment: I don't get it, why do you need a DC out of an image? Get the DC of window, draw on it.

Comment: `StretchBlt` for example takes two DC arguments, the first one is the destination and the second on is the Destination. And my source is the image

Comment: Well, you are writing on image, which you've just loaded. Try without performing stretching/block transfer operations